# Effective online marketing alternatives to social media

Tags: fiction, self-publishing, marketing

Every online resource and forum seems to be emphasizing the importance of social media marketing for a book series. I currently have two social media profiles (Facebook, Twitter) and a personal website talking about my writing.

My series is fictional, focused towards the YA audience. My first book has been in print and eBook for a year now, with the second book in the series releasing at the end of this year.

**My main question is:** *Besides* social media, what are other effective online methods of marketing a self published book/series?

Also, should I be focusing on the individual books themselves, or try to market the series as a whole?

Comment: Check Amazon Marketing Service (AMS) after first studying keywords in great depth. You'll need to do a lot of research on how to use this effectively or will simply be wasting money.

Comment: I've always been hesitant about the Amazon or Kindle marketing packages. Mostly because I don't know enough about them, and I wonder how effective they actually are. I'll have to do more research like you suggested. Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Besides social media, what are other effective online methods of marketing a self published book/series?

### You're referring to **[digital marketing](http://popcontent.co.uk/different-types-of-digital-marketing/)**.

As the link foretells, there are a variety of different types (which are rightfully debated in marketing circles). This link in particular lists:

1. Pay Per Click Advertising/ SEO: Sponsored links on search engines
2. Public Relations
3. Social Media Marketing: facebook, twitter, etc
4. Content Marketing: blog posts, articles, youtube videos, podcasts, etc
5. Affiliate Marketing: Pay others a share of profits if they advertise you
6. Viral Marketing: Make content that goes viral-> free advertising
7. Influence Marketing: pay someone with influence over your target audience to advertise the product or service.
8. Website Marketing: Basically a website w/ SEO

> Also, should I be focusing on the individual books themselves, or try to market the series as a whole?

### Do both and track them separately.

You'll see how successful each campaign message is, which in turn tells you what works and what doesn't. The faster you can recycle feedback into better messaging, the faster you'll see improvements in marketing.

Comment: Accepted for providing several alternatives as well as answering my concerns about how I should market my story. Great answer, thank you very much! +1

Answer (score 1):

I believe that besides social media, if you invest on a ad based on targeting the most healthy neighbourhoods where you think your product will be valued, a branding campaign for your local community magazine would benefit you a lot.